# Wordpress theme not displaying properly, problem with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress, css

I hope this is the right forum for my question. I installed WordPress on the free host [x10hosting](http://x10hosting.com/), and everything seems to work fine except when I try to install a custom theme. The theme is not displaying properly at all, and I assume the css is not being rendered by the *web server*, I tried adding an .htaccess file as advice from a google search, and messed around with that but it doesn't seem to be doing anything, I'm not even sure if it could make a difference. Does anyone know why the theme (css *web server* rendering) would not be displaying properly?

Thanks.

Comment: btw - CSS doesn't render on the web *server*, it renders in the web *browser*

Answer (score 1):

O my, it seems I forgot to change the file permissions of the theme's directory. Got it!

Comment: sometimes it's those basic things that bite us in the rump :)